# NLog logger name missing from the log file, do you see why?

Tags: asp.net, nlog

I am logging from an ASP.NET app using NLog. Everything works great except for the ${logger}. My log files are missing the logger name. Here is the target line from NLog configuration file:

```
<target name="DebugToFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/Debug.log" layout="${logger} | ${longdate} | ${message}" />
```

Here is what I get in the log file:

```
| 2013-10-05 17:55:20.9852 | In Decrypt
| 2013-10-05 17:55:20.9852 | In Deserialize
```

And here is the C# line that creates an instance of the logger:

```
new Log("Iamalogger").Debug("In Decrypt");
```

Any ideas why ${logger} isn't getting picked up?

**Edit: 1/14/2014**
Here is the log wrapper I am using:

```
public class Log 
{
    private Logger _log;

    public Log(string class)
    {
        _log = LogManager.GetLogger(class);
    }

    //methods for logging...
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for your Log class?

Comment: As @wageoghe says, it seems like you are using a customer Log class, is this correct? If so please provide the source code for the class

Comment: Sorry, this got pushed down on my priority. Just updated with the code from the Log wrapper I am using.

Answer (score 0):

*I know this is an old question, but I stumbled upon this problem recently, so I'd like to show what was wrong with my implementation in case someone else finds itself in this situation.*

Since the log wrapper in the question doesn't show the implementation of the `Debug` method, I'll assume it was something like the implementation that I did in my wrapper:

```
public class Log
{
    private Logger _log;

    public Log (string className)
    {
        _log = LogManager.GetLogger(className);
    }

    public void Debug(string message)
    {
        _log.Log(new LogEventInfo
        {
            TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
            Level = LogLevel.Debug,
            Message = message,
        });
    }
}
```

...and, of course, if we use this class like this:

```
new Log("Iamalogger").Debug("In Decrypt");
```

the log is missing the logger name:

```
 | 2018-05-13 15:58:06.1805 | In Decrypt
```

**The solution** was to set the value to the `LoggerName` property in the `LogEventInfo`:

```
public void Debug(string message)
{
    _log.Log(new LogEventInfo
    {
        TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
        Level = LogLevel.Debug,
        Message = message,
        LoggerName = _log.Name
    });
}
```

or using the constructor that accepts the logger name:

```
public void Debug(string message)
{
    _log.Log(new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Debug, _log.Name, message)
    {
        TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow
    });
}
```

resulting in the following log being written:

```
Iamalogger | 2018-05-13 16:18:16.1201 | In Decrypt
```